# Unable to test google voice actions from connected device

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, mobile-devices

I have created an agent on dialogflow.com (earlier api.ai) and then added Google Assistant as the integration. It then after configuration allows me to interact using the simulator.

On the simulator it is clearly written, "Test your app by typing or saying "Talk to your app" below or any device you're logged into with "my.account@gmail.com" but that is not working from my device.

Please help.

Comment: You should check that you are login with the same gmail on both your device (which is it?) and the web simulator. Also, is it working in the web simulator?

Comment: Yes it is working in the web simulator.

I have cross verified properly that I have logged in with the same gmail account. Is there any other thing that I can check?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the simulator showing you invoking it and confirm exactly what you are saying to your device? What device are you trying to use that isn't working?